# Exporting large png results in completely black image

Tags: export, bugs, image, version-8

When trying to export an `Image` as PNG the resulting file is a completely black image. This happens only for certain images I have not been able to determine exactly which, so I uploaded [a notebook that triggers it](http://ge.tt/2cFM59n/v/0). Is this a known bug with a known fix?

[image: brokenness screenshot]

Some system info:

```
Fedora 19 3.9.9-302.fc19.x86_64
Mathematica 8.0.4
8Gb RAM
```

Comment: Looks fine on Mac OS X, Mathematica 9...

Comment: Looks fine [for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/779vv.png)

Comment: Looks good on Windows 7, Mathematica 9.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. So I guess linux specific, v8 specific or ssch specific

Comment: Mac OS X, Mathematica 8, reproduces the black square.

Comment: Your noteboook worked for me in Mathematica 9.0 but not in Mathematica 8.0. OpenSuse Linux 12.2 Mathematica 9.0; Linux 3.4.47-2.38-desktop x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: On Windows 7 MMA8 has the black box, and as g3kk0 noted it works on MMA9. So this seems to be a version related issue independent of platform.

Comment: Ok with Mathematica 7.0.1.0 on Windows 7.  Interesting image.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the comments this is a bug in version 8 on all platforms. Specifically I think, a bug in PNG.EXE that Mathematica 8 uses to import PNG files.

On windows, it is located here:

> C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\PNG.exe

No such file exists in my version 9.0 converters folder, so I assume importing PNGs has been internalized (and, apparently, improved).

A workaround would be to import/export as tiff. The resulting image in Mathematica is the same as before. If a PNG is desired an external converter could be used to convert TIFFS to PNGs.